# How to remove style of all Divs matching particular criteria?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having following HTML structure=>

```
<span style="font-size:13px;">
<div style="margin-top:14pt;margin-bottom:1em;"><br>

<font size="1"><span style="font-size:12px;"><b>Name:</b></span></font><font size="1"><span style="font-size:12px;"> pratikJj jj</span></font></div>
<div style="margin-top:14pt;margin-bottom:1em;"><font size="1"><span style="font-size:12px;"><b>Email:</b> <a target="_blank" href="redir.aspx?C=AqQ9qrS3S0CCUr8wYx3QUu0HmT-cF9EI3kjBzIy3J26HoWKecGaL2VVHKtRt0q8meK1S8kDowtw.&amp;URL=mailto%3apratik.joshi%40aressindia.net">pratik.joshi@aressindia.net</a></span></font></div>
<div style="margin-top:14pt;margin-bottom:1em;"><font size="1"><span style="font-size:12px;"><b>Phone Number:</b></span></font><font size="1"><span style="font-size:12px;"> 919999999999</span></font></div>
<div style="margin-top:14pt;margin-bottom:1em;"><font size="1"><span style="font-size:12px;"><b>Name Of Facility:</b> sdsd</span></font></div>
<div style="margin-top:14pt;margin-bottom:1em;"><font size="1"><span style="font-size:12px;">&nbsp;</span></font></div>
</span>
```

This is what I want to do =>

If the div is containing following style

```
margin-top:14pt;margin-bottom:1em;
```

Then styling should be blank or for example style=""

Comment: I really don't get it. You can just make a class in an external stylesheet and add the class to those divs? *confused*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/),

```
$('div[style*="margin-top:14pt;margin-bottom:1em;"]').removeAttr("style");
```

Comment: I liked that you used `*=`

Answer (score 0):

Would it be easier (cleaner) if you had classes on the divs?

Then basically adapt the same answer that Rajaprabhu provided:

```
$(".className").removeAttr('style');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would move styles to CSS and classes, then use following statements: `getElementsByClassName`, `classList.remove`.
You can find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) and [there](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName).

Answer (score 0):

As stated above I would move all your styles from your HTML markup and instead put them into CSS. Then take advantage of JavaScript/jQuery selectors.

Also, take note: the `<font>` tag is not supported in HTML5.